# Árvore binária de busca em C

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Preciso desenvolver um algoritmo que ache o maior valor da soma de todos os nós dos mais variados percursos possíveis de uma árvore binária de busca em C.

Por exemplo, a árvore:

```
                        50

           30                   90

      20        40                    95

   10       35        45
```

Tem os seguintes caminhos da raiz até as folhas:

- 50, 30, 20, 10 = 110 (soma)
- 50, 30, 40, 35 = 155 (soma)
- 50, 30, 40, 45 = 165 (soma)
- 50, 90, 95 = 235 (soma)

O valor do maior deles é: 235.

Como faço para fazer ele percorrer todos os diferentes caminhos e armazenar os valores das somas do percurso para comparar? Do jeito que eu fiz eu estou comparando o ramo mais a esquerda com o ramo mais a direita

Segue o código que estou usando abaixo.
Obrigado

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

/***************** Arvore.h *********************/

typedef struct _arvore {
   int info;
   struct _arvore *esq;
   struct _arvore *dir;
} Arvore;

Arvore* cria_arv_vazia ();

Arvore* Remover (Arvore *a, int v);

void destroi_arv (Arvore *arv);

Arvore* constroi_arv (int elem, Arvore *esq, Arvore *dir);

int min (Arvore *a);

int max (Arvore *a);

void imprime_decrescente (Arvore *a);

int maior_ramo (Arvore *a);


/***************** Arvore.c *********************/

/*Cria uma arvore vazia!*/
Arvore* cria_arv_vazia () {
   return NULL;
}

/*Destroi uma arvore!*/
void destroi_arv (Arvore *arv) {
   if (arv != NULL) {
      destroi_arv (arv->esq);
      destroi_arv (arv->dir);
      free(arv);
   }
}

/*Cria um no em uma arvore!*/
Arvore* inserir (Arvore *a, int v){
    if(a == NULL){
        a=(Arvore*)malloc(sizeof(Arvore));
        a->info = v;
        a->esq = NULL;
        a->dir = NULL;
    }
    else if(v < a->info){
        a->esq = inserir(a->esq,v);
    }
    else{
        a->dir = inserir(a->dir,v);
    }
    return a;
}



void pre_ordem (Arvore *arv) {
    if (arv != NULL){
       printf ("%d, ", arv->info);
       pre_ordem (arv->esq);
       pre_ordem (arv->dir);

    }
}

void in_ordem (Arvore *arv) {
   if (arv != NULL) {
      in_ordem (arv->esq);
      printf ("%d, ", arv->info);
      in_ordem (arv->dir);
   }
}

void pos_ordem (Arvore *arv){
    if (arv != NULL){
        pos_ordem (arv->esq);
        pos_ordem (arv->dir);
        printf("%d, ", arv->info);
    }
}

int buscar (Arvore *a, int v){
    if(a==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(v < a->info){
        return buscar(a->esq,v);
    }
    else if(v > a->info){
        return buscar(a->dir,v);
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int min (Arvore *a){
    if( a->esq != NULL){
        return min(a->esq);
    }
    else{
         return a->info;
    }
}

int max (Arvore *a){
    if (a->dir != NULL){
        return max(a->dir);
    }
    else{
        return a->info;
    }
}

Arvore* Remover (Arvore *a, int v){
    if(a == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        if(a->info >v){
            a->esq = Remover (a->esq,v);
        }
        else if (a->info <v){
            a->dir = Remover (a->dir,v);
        }
        else{
            if((a->esq == NULL) && (a->dir == NULL)){
                free(a);
                a=NULL;
            }
            else if(a->dir == NULL){
                Arvore *tmp = a;
                a = a -> esq;
                free (tmp);
            }
            else if(a->esq == NULL){
                Arvore *tmp = a;
                a = a -> dir;
                free (tmp);
            }
            else{
                Arvore *tmp = a->esq;
                while(tmp->dir != NULL){
                    tmp=tmp->dir;
                }
                a->info = tmp->info;
                tmp->info = v;
                a->esq = Remover(a->esq,v);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}


void imprime_decrescente (Arvore *arv){
    if (arv != NULL){
        printf("%d, ", max(arv));
        imprime_decrescente(Remover(arv, max(arv)));

    }
}


int contarNos(Arvore *a){
   if(a == NULL)
        return 0;
   else
        return 1 + contarNos(a->esq) + contarNos(a->dir);
}

int maior(int a, int b){
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

int maior_ramo(Arvore *a){
   if((a == NULL)){
        return 0;
   }
   else{
        return maior(maior_ramo(a->dir) +a-> info, maior_ramo(a->esq) + a->info);
   }
}


/****************** Prog.c **********************/

int main () {

Arvore *a = cria_arv_vazia ();

a = inserir (a, 50);
a = inserir (a, 30);
a = inserir (a, 90);
a = inserir (a, 20);
a = inserir (a, 40);
a = inserir (a, 95);
a = inserir (a, 10);
a = inserir (a, 35);
a = inserir (a, 45);




printf("%d",maior_ramo(a));

return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código já está encontrando a maior soma, só falta uma estrutura para armazenar o percurso. Por exemplo, no lugar de retornar apenas o valor da soma, retornar uma estrutura que contém a soma e uma lista do percurso.

Estrutura lista para armazenar percurso.

```
typedef struct _node {
   int info;
   int soma;
   struct _node *proximo;
} Node;
```

Então basta altera a função `maior_ramo`:

```
Node* maior_ramo(Arvore *a){
    Node *atual = (Node) malloc (sizeof (data));
    if((a == NULL)){
        atual->info = 0;
        atual->soma = 0;
        atual->proximo = NULL;
        return atual;
    }
    else{
        Node *dir = maior_ramo(a->dir);
        Node *esq = maior_ramo(a->esq);
        Node *atual = (Node) malloc (sizeof (data));
        if (dir->soma >= esq->soma) {
            atual->soma = dir->soma;
            atual->proximo = dir;
        } else {
            atual->info = esq->soma;
            atual->proximo = esq;
        }
        atual->info = a->info;
        atual->soma += a->info;
        return atual;
    }
}
```

E na função `main` ficaria:

```
int main () {
    Arvore *a = cria_arv_vazia ();

    a = inserir (a, 50);
    a = inserir (a, 30);
    a = inserir (a, 90);
    a = inserir (a, 20);
    a = inserir (a, 40);
    a = inserir (a, 95);
    a = inserir (a, 10);
    a = inserir (a, 35);
    a = inserir (a, 45);

    Node *raiz = maior_ramo(a);

    printf("Maior soma: %d\n", raiz->soma);
    printf("Percurso:\n");
    while (raiz->proximo != NULL) {
        printf("  %d\n", raiz->info);
        raiz = raiz->proximo;
    }

    return 0;
}
```